# How to speed collection "contains" execution plan?

Tags: java

If I make analogy to Oracle database : they have the notion of "index" and "hint" to **speed** the execution of a query. So I want to make the analogy to `Java` : is it possible to make the execution of the "`contains`" method of a `collection` to be quick ?

Comment: Use a collection that runs `contains` in constant time, such as `HashSet` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible to make the execution of the "contains" method of a collection to be quick ?

Yes, use a collection with a faster `contains` method.

e.g.

```
HashSet -> O(1)
SortedSet -> O(ln N)
List -> O(N)
```

The big-O time complexity indicates how the worst case time for an operation as the size of the collection grows. Lower time complexity is faster for modest to large collections.

Note: this only tells you how the collection scales. If the collection is very small like 1 or 2, then a List might be the fastest.

The `Big-O` notation is well explained [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: can you explain your notation please ?

Comment: @pheromix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation

Comment: @pheromix not all collections have the same speed for certain operations, using a collection which is faster at performing the operation you need speeds it up.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm wondering which is more difficult: google or show comments.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you want to do with that collection. These are the **standard** options:

1. If the order of insertion doesn't matter, then you can use a `HashSet`. Once you have this `Set` set up, the `contains()` method will run in O(constant) time.
2. Alternatively, you can use a `LinkedHashSet`. It is almost the same as the `HashSet`, but it maintains a `LinkedList` on the top of the Set so you can maintain the order of original insertion.
3. If you want to maintain the *natural ordering* of your items, you can use a *TreeSet*. Its `contains()` method will return in O(log n) time which is still fairly quick.

If none of these is good for you, then you can have your collection, assign another `HashSet` and maintain them together. However, I'm afraid that the performance gain isn't justified at most of the cases.

Comment: what does mean the `O` notation ?

Comment: It's the notation to measure complexity. It's well explained https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/4723795

Comment: The big-oh notation shows the time required for computing the results *compared to the input size*. I.e. `O(n)` means that if the list becomes twice as big, the `contains()` will run twice as much. `O(constant)` means that the run time is independent from the `Set` size - this is the very cool. `O(log n)` means that if the `TreeSet` becomes twice as big, the `contains` will run sg like 1.2 times as much.